# MySQL nested Json Object using nodeJs

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, group-by

I have two MySQL tables

```
category(id, name)
product(id, name, category_id)
```

`product(category_id)` is a foreign key to `category(id)`, the relationship is one to many to one relationship so one category can have numerous products.

I am trying to get this from the database and return it in JSON format for multiple categories, so it would look like this:

```
 [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Category 1",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Chicken"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Beef"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Category 2",
    "products": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "item": "Fries"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "item": "Burgers"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Where the products are nested within the entity of their corresponding category.

I am a newbie and not sure how i would reproduce this using nodeJs from MySQL. Kindly assist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use [json generator function `json_object()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html) and [json aggregate function `json_arrayagg()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg).

The following query produces one record per category, each holding a json object:

```
select 
    json_object(
        'id', c.id,
        'name', c.name,
        'products', json_arrayagg(
            json_object(
                'id', p.id,
                'name', p.name
            )
        )
    ) cat
from category c
inner join product p on p.category_id = c.id
group by c.id, c.name
```

If you want to aggregate all records in a unique json array, then you can add another level of aggregation:

```
select json_arrayagg(cat)
from (
    select 
        json_object(
            'id', c.id,
            'name', c.name,
            'products', json_arrayagg(
                json_object(
                    'id', p.id,
                    'name', p.name
                )
            )
        ) cat
    from category c
    inner join product p on p.category_id = c.id
    group by c.id, c.name   
) t
```